# http json file retrieving with IONIC and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I am working on an product reviewing app based on ionic framework.
The app will consume REST service in JSON format.

Because Im not able to retireve data directly from the locally deployed website, i created a json demo file:

```
[{
    "index": 0, 
    "marque": "labore", 
    "estAutorise": 0, 
    "name": "Jennifer Simmons"
  }, 
  {
    "index": 1, 
    "marque": "duis", 
    "estAutorise": 0, 
    "name": "Beatriz Hale"
  }, 
  {
    "index": 2, 
    "marque": "pariatur", 
    "estAutorise": 1, 
    "name": "Richmond Garner"
  }
]
```

here is my services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Recettes', function($http) {
  var recettes = [];
  var produits = [];

    $http.get('test.json').success(function(data) { 
        alert("success"); //to check the seccess responce
        produits= data;
    });
return {
...
    produits: function() {
      return produits;
},
....
```

Before this, I implemented products and recettes directly and it works just fine. And now, I recieve the success alert but the data seems to be invalid.

My controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Recettes) {
  $scope.produits = Recettes.produits();
})
...
```

So my question is how can i fix the data binding problem ?
And If it works with .json file should it work for rest services as well (Content-Type: application/json )?
Thank you.

Comment: I bet if you put an alert or log to the console in your `prodouits` function it's finishing before your AJAX request.

Comment: I tested it by changing to the URL to a non-existing file and it skipped the alert. I'm really out of ideas.